# In App Purchase : Two devices with same account not getting same purchased items

Tags: android, in-app-billing

**What I am trying?**

Purchasing items in one android device having configured X email address. When I check in another device having the same email address configured. but items purchased on first device is not getting available in another device.

**What I have tried?**

I have tried using :

```
inappBillingService.getPurchases(InAppBuyActivity.INAPPVERSION,
                    getPackageName(), "inapp", null);
```

and also tried using :

```
IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mGotInventoryListener
   = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
   public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result,
      Inventory inventory) {

      if (result.isFailure()) {
        // handle error here
      }
      else {
        // Not getting same purchased on both devices
      }
   }
};
```

I am generating signed apk having the same version name and version code as of playstore version.

Comment: Why aren't you using `IabBillingHelper` class?

Comment: @azizbekian second already using IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener

Comment: `IabBillingHelper` has something like `getPurchases()`, why don't you use that API to get your purchases?

Comment: @azizbekian IabHelper class giving QueryInventoryFinishedListener and InAppBillingService giving getPurchases(). I tried both which are available in question.

Comment: Is the second device has same google account as the primary email in playstore app? I think it takes time to sync the purchases..

Comment: @sravs second device has same single account. It takes time to reflect purchases. But, i want all purchased items when user open the app.

Comment: It is the issue at google side..I don't think we can do anything to solve this..but try to call getPurchases for 2 to 3 time so that it might sync the data..I haven't tried the above hack..u just try it.

Comment: What does happen when you try to purchase same item in the second device?

Comment: @MaximG it shows already purchased. But i need all purchased item when query using both ways which i mensioned in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested the app using two devices. It takes sometime to reflect the purchases.

If i delete the app and reinstall it as a fresh then new purchased items are there. But, if i purchase one item and check it on second device at same time its not reflected there.

App shows items already purchased in second device when user try to purchase it. But, its not available in `inappBillingService.getPurchases` and `IabHelper.QueryInventory`.

Answer (score 0):

The In-app Billing Version 3 API makes it easier for you to integrate In-app Billing into your applications.The features in this version include improved synchronous purchase flow, APIs to let you easily track ownership of consumable goods, and local caching of in-app purchase data.

**1. Check in your code, if you used consumable or not**

if you used consumable, user can purchase product multiple time, google store only one time purchase detail and again getting blank response, so remove consumable related code from your app.

**2. Check user already purchased item or not using below code**

```
private IInAppBillingService mService = null;

//onCreare
try {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent("com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND");
        serviceIntent.setPackage("com.android.vending");
        bindService(serviceIntent, mServiceConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
      //  bindService(new Intent("com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND"), mServiceConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


// Method 
 ServiceConnection mServiceConn = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        mService = IInAppBillingService.Stub.asInterface(service);
        Log.d("TEST", "mService ready to go!");
        checkownedItems();
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        mService = null;
    }
};

private void checkownedItems() {
    try {
        Bundle ownedItems = mService.getPurchases(3, getPackageName(), "inapp", null);
        if (ownedItems.getInt("RESPONSE_CODE") == 0) {
            ArrayList<String> ownedSkus = ownedItems.getStringArrayList("INAPP_PURCHASE_ITEM_LIST");
            ArrayList<String> purchaseDataList = ownedItems.getStringArrayList("INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA_LIST");


            if (purchaseDataList.size() > 0) {
                // Item already Purchased....
                // Manage your in-app view

            }else{
               // Item not purchased
             }
        }

    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Used above logic before purchase item, if item not purchase then call in-app getPurchases() otherwise hide or manage in-app view.

Comment: Items are not consumable. User only purchase it for single time. Same code is there for connection and get purchases.

Comment: @SANAT, have you check ownedSkus and purchaseDataList value ?

Comment: i checked "INAPP_PURCHASE_ITEM_LIST" from getPurchases result.
Bundle ownedItems = mService.getPurchases(InAppBuyActivity.INAPPVERSION,
                    getPackageName(), "inapp", null);
ArrayList<String> ownedSkus =
                        ownedItems.getStringArrayList("INAPP_PURCHASE_ITEM_LIST");

Comment: Intent serviceIntent = new Intent("com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND");
        serviceIntent.setPackage("com.android.vending");
        bindService(serviceIntent, mServiceConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE); 
Call before purchase item and check, if already purchase item it must be return any value in ownedSkus and purchaseDataList array.